# Convert Git into TFVC with history

Tags: tfs, repository, tfvc, git-repo

**Is there any tool to convert Git Repos into TFVC with history *or* convert TFS into TFVC including the history?**

Answer (score 0):

[Git-TFS](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) will do this, but be aware that TFVC and Git are very different models for source control so the tool may not be able to get all history of all branches. Some historic actions inside TFVC may cause the tool to fail (such as branch Renames).

The best way to figure out if you have a problem is to run the tool against your TFVC instance.

run something like

```
git tfs clone http://tfsServer:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection $/Project1/Trunk --branches=all
```

Or

```
git tfs clone http://dev.azure.com/organisation $/Project1/Trunk --branches=all
```

And see what happens. This command will create a local Git Repo which you can look at to ensure all of your branches and history have been converted